# Как по касанию в GridView менять картинку?

Tags: android, gridview, ontouchlistener

Здравствуйте. У меня есть `GridView` c обычным адаптером как в [примере](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Можно ли сделать так, что бы при нажатии на соответствующий элемент в `GridView`, заменить его на другую картинку, если касания нет, картинка снова становится прежней. Что то типа `OnTouchListener`.

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

`GridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener {
    onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
      // поменять картинку
   }
 }
 );`